# Add a property at a specific position to a json string with jackson json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I know how to add a property using jackson with `ObjectNode.put()` but is there a way to insert the property at a specific position?
For example if I have this JsonNode:

```
{
    "property1":"val1",
    "property2":"val2",
    "property3":"val3"
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
    "property1":"val1",
    "property4":"val4",
    "property2":"val2",
    "property3":"val3"
}
```

How can I achieve that with Jackson?

Comment: Object property order should not matter. Why do you care?

Comment: I'm parsing a json file and I want to add a property at specific position then write back. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you care about the specific "position?" Why does it matter?

Comment: The file is used for configuration and it is well formatted, I don't want to make it messy.

Comment: Is it a huge node or is it ok to copy it ?

Answer (score 2):

The JSON spec does not require the objects to be ordered (they may or may not be depending on the implementation), so you should not rely on it. Arrays, however, are explicitly ordered:

> ## 6 Objects
>
> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens surrounding zero or more name/value pairs.  A 
>   name  is  a  string .  A  single  colon  token  follows  each  name, 
>   separating  the  name  from  the  value .  A  single  comma token
>   separates a  value  from a following name.
>
> ## 7 Arrays
>
> An  array  structure  is  a  pair  of  square  bracket 
>   tokens  surrounding  zero  or  more  values .  The  values   are 
>   separated by commas. The order of the  values  is significant.

(from http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

Comment: Oh okay, now I see that the order of properties doesn't really matter. What I'm trying to do is to read a json formatted file, add some properties at a specific position, write back and save the file. The file is well formatted and used for configuration, I don't want to make it messy, so that's why I want to put properties in order.

Comment: The file is about 37 MB, should be ok to copy it.

Comment: I was just thinking that since Jackson internally uses `LinkedHasMap` you could re-populate the whole object every time you want to insert into it somewhere else than at the end. However, 37 MB is not so small and it would be inefficient. By the way, it might stop working at the next version of Jackson or using another JSON library. All that to say I don't recommend it. Maybe JSON is not the format you want, or maybe you need arrays instead of objects

Answer (score 2):

Use an `ObjectMapper` and either use `@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic=true)` or an explicitly-specified ordering.

- [Jackson ObjectMapper - specify serialization order of object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577701/jackson-objectmapper-specify-serialization-order-of-object-properties)
- [Order of JSON objects using Jackson's ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19272830/139010)

Comment: Oh good, I guess `ObjectMapper` is what I want, I'll give a try, thanks!

Comment: That's nice, but it's assuming that his config is held in a single class, which might not be the case, it might just be data for example. In this case, he would have to write a 100% boilerplate class, which might be acceptable but is arguably not great

Comment: Hi Matt, is it possible to handle it without serialization? To be clear, what I want to do is to read a json file, insert a property then write back to the file.

Comment: What do you mean by "without serialization?" Writing a file as JSON _is_ serialization.

Comment: Hmm... okay, from my understanding, I need to create classes to handle the data if I want to write back. Is that true? For example if I have a car object, I need to have a car class to handle the data, then modify data and write back to the file. Can I just modify the json file without those classes?