# How do i preserve the original order of json with JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I am using the JSONArray object and I am passing to the constructor of that object a string. The string that I'm passing is

`[{\"x\":18.4300,\"y\":30.4700,\"w\":53.0900,\"fontSize\": 11,\"bold\": 0,\"charcount\": 22,\"id\": 349133}]`.

After out-printing the json object, I get the following:

`[{"charcount":22,"w":53.09,"x":18.43,"y":30.47,"fontSize":11,"bold":0,"id":349133}]`.

Can I get an example in code of how I can preserve the order of the original json string?

Comment: JSON (like a HashMap), has no natural ordering. This is an XY Problem unless you explain why order matters

Comment: you could replace JSONArray with Jackson see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272830/order-of-json-objects-using-jacksons-objectmapper

Answer (score 0):

You can use a an ordered collection to parse your json to keep it's order.
A sample for your json:

```
    String json = "[{\"x\":18.4300,\"y\":30.4700,\"w\":53.0900,\"fontSize\": 11,\"bold\": 0,\"charcount\": 22,\"id\": 349133}]";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Set<LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>>>() {}.getType();
    Set<LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>> myMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(myMap);
```