# Jackson's @JsonPropertyOrder doesn't work with @JsonUnwrapped

Tags: java, json, orders

I have an object that contains another object attribute like this:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonUnwrapped;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Data;

@JsonPropertyOrder({"fA1","b","fA2"})
@Data
public class A {
    private String fA1;
    private String fA2;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private B b = new B();

    @Data
    class B {
        private String fB1;
        private String fB2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        A a = new A ();
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a));
    }

}
```

what i want is generate json that respect this order :

```
{
  "fA1":"",
  "fB1":"",
  "fA2":"",
  "fB2":""
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please check out this answer and tell if it suits you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272830/order-of-json-objects-using-jacksons-objectmapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1670) in the jackson-databind repository on GitHub, the [`@JsonPropertyOrder`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html) annotation doesn't work with [`@JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation. See the quote below:

> True, unwrapped properties are not included in ordering, since they are not really known by enclosing serializer as regular properties. And specifically, as things are, will be output as a block of properties per contained, so even if known they can not be reordered separately.
>
> Perhaps something could be done with Jackson 3.x once we get there.

---

But you may consider a **workaround**: as you seem to be using Lombok, you could annotate `b` with [`@Delegate`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/experimental/Delegate.html) and [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html):

```java
@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder({"fa1", "fb1", "fa2", "fb2"})
public class A {

    private String fA1;
    private String fA2;

    @Delegate
    @JsonIgnore
    private B b = new B();
}
```

The [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) annotation will ensure that the `b` property is not serialized by Jackson.

And the [`@Delegate`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/experimental/Delegate.html) annotation will tell Lombok to generate delegate methods that forward the call to the `B` methods. With that, the `A` class will have getters and setters that are delegated to the getters and setters of the `fB1` and `fB2` fields.

Comment: so what is the solution

Comment: @MoradAngel I've updated my answer with one possible solution.

Comment: you are a hero, can you explain me the @delegate and i accept the answer

Comment: @MoradAngel I've added details to my answer.