# Generate json request body using Lombok annotation

Tags: java, lombok, rest-assured

I tried multiple pattern , but still no success how can I create JSON Array object with nested JSON object similar like below

```
{
  "deduction": [
    {
      "id": "50258779",
      "amount": {
        "value": 13.24,
        "currency": "INR"
      },
      "transfer": "DEPOSIT",
      "fund": "RL",
      "description": "TD description",
      "code": "codeNumber"
    },
    {
      "id": "50258779",
      "amount": {
        "value": 13.24,
        "currency": "INR"
      },
      "transfer": "DEPOSIT",
      "fund": "RL",
      "description": "TD description",
      "code": "codeNumber"
    }
  ]
}
```

I had generated Class to build this request schema :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;


@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Transf{

    private List<Deduction> deduction;

    @Builder
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Deduction {

        private Amount amount;
        private String transfer;
        private String code;
        private String fund;
        private String description;
        private Integer id;

    }

    @Builder
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Amount {

        private String currency;
        private Double value;

    }
}
```

Trying to create json request body to be send using rest assured

```
public Transf trans()
    {
        return Transf.builder()
            .deduction(Transf.Deduction.builder().transfer("")).build();
    }
```

But getting syntax error on this , need to know how can I make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you define `private List<Deduction> deduction;` --> you will supply `List`.

Second, to make builder work, you have to call `.build()`

```
public Transf trans() {
    return Transf.builder()
            .deduction(Arrays.asList(Transf.Deduction.builder().transfer("").build()))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but is it possible to display the json body constructed in same pattern , I mean why Transf.Deduction.builder().transfer("") is showing in middle of other json object ?

Comment: @Cod I don't understand your question. Do you mean how to view your POJO in json format?

Comment: hey not exactly , I am mean the order of json element , its random

Comment: @Cod Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272931/7574461

Comment: Yes , thanks got what I needed and also some new content as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Transf.Deduction.builder().transfer("")
```

you need to have

```
Transf.Deduction.builder().transfer("").build()
```